# .wac to .wav conversion

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine, game-engine, wav

I've been asked to sample some data in a **.wac** file type. I'm not familiar with this standard and there is very little on the internet with regards to this format. I got given the **.wav** file but I don't think it was converted correctly, in that there was a none existent of the `RIFF` header so no .wav reader was able to read it.

Could anyone therefore shed some light into how I could possibly convert the .wac file into a .wav file? Doing some research, I cannot seem to find a converter tool on the internet, and, MatLab does not have a module for reading in .wac data.

NOTE: I've put the tag "game-engine" because according to this website: [Here](http://filext.com/file-extension/WAC) it is used in the infinity game engine.

Comment: For anybody getting to this question because they wish to convert a .wac file to .wav...but in the case where the .wac is a "wildlife acoustics files", there is some code that Wildlife Acoustics has open sources that allows for scripting the conversion instead of having to use their GUI software. Check their blog, or go to: http://www.wildlifeacoustics.com/downloads/wac2wavcmd-1.0.zip  hopefully helps somebody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come up with the following solution, however, massive thanks to @jpaari for his input.

Basically, I used `sox`:

`sox -r 44100 -e unsigned -b 8 -c 1 input.raw output.wav`

I was able to re-name the file to .raw and this worked. I'm going to update the Sample Rate to what @Aybe posted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://www.shsforums.net/topic/39117-ps-gui-v304/

I think Audacity can do it aswell. Also the "unity3d" tag is not quite right.

Comment: It's a simple container which format is described here : http://gemrb.org/iesdp/file_formats/ie_formats/wavc_v1.htm