# Sox - Converting files Sample rate not specified

Tags: audio, wav, sox

This is a follow up question from: [wac-to-wav-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928357/wac-to-wav-conversion)

I have changed the file extension from .wac to .raw and used the following command:

```
sox -r 44100 -e unsigned -b 8 -c 1 input.raw output.wav
```

This converts to the .wav file, however distorts the sound massively, for example:

[image]

Where it should be the following:

[image]

There is a massive difference and I can't seem to figure out where it is I am going wrong. I have also tried the following:

```
sox input.raw --bits 16 --encoding signed-integer --endian little 
output.wav
```

But I just get the following:

> sox FAIL formats: bad input format for file `input.raw': sampling rate was not specified

Does anyone know of a way to set the sampling rate, so the file is correct?

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to tell from the graphs, but maybe the raw file is signed data? Just change "-e unsigned" to "-e signed". You could also try with different sample widths, i.e. "-b 16" or "-b 32".